# Assigning object inside foreach using Entity Framework is extremely slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, foreach, linq-to-sql

I'm having a problem with assigning an object inside foreach loop using Entity Framework, I don't know why it's taking very long time (Almost 48 seconds for 1800 items in the loop!!).

Sample Code:

```
using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
     foreach (long r in Recipients) //Recipients has 1800 items.
     {
         var temp = new DirectMessage();
         temp = db.DirectMessages().FirstOrDefault();
         temp.SenderProfileImageUrl = "https://www.google.com.sa/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png";    
     }
}
```

This simple loop is taking around 45 seconds!!

At testing and debugging, I noticed that this command `temp = db.DirectMessages().FirstOrDefault();` is making the delay!

Also, originally it had `.Where` and `.OrderBy` using `r.ID` but I changed it to the simplest way to make sure the delay is not from the filtering.

**Update, Original Code:**

```
foreach (long r in Recipients)
                {
                    MsgObj = new AllMsgsClass();

                    MsgObj.LastMsg = db.DirectMessages.Where(a => (a.SenderID == r || a.RecipientID == r)).OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedDate).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

                    try
                    {
                        if (MsgObj.LastMsg.MsgSort == "Sent")
                            MsgObj.LastMsg.RecipientProfileImageUrl = "https://avatars.io/twitter/" + MsgObj.LastMsg.RecipientScreenName + "/small";

                        else
                            MsgObj.LastMsg.SenderProfileImageUrl = "https://avatars.io/twitter/" + MsgObj.LastMsg.SenderScreenName + "/small";
                    }
                    catch (Exception dd)
                    {
                        string x = dd.Message;
                    }

                    MsgObj.SortOrder = Convert.ToDateTime(MsgObj.LastMsg.CreatedDate);
                    AllMSGsList.Add(MsgObj);
                }
```

Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: Do you really need to re-query the same item from DB 1800 times? Why don't you cache this item into local variable?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do have for two reasons, to get the latest profile picture by user ID (in the question I just put google icon), and to do some sorting before binding.

Comment: Could you post your *real* code?

Comment: @Dennis Posted, thank you

Comment: Your real SQL query is more complex, than `FirstOrDefault`, since you're searching by `SenderID` or `RecipientID`, and do ordering. Do profile it against database - may be, this is just a missing index(-es) case

Comment: @Dennis both queries are taking the same time! either `FirstOrDefault` or the Complex one! but anyway, what columns I should add index for in the db?

Comment: You need to retrieve query execution plan, and analyze it. For SQL Server use Management Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `db.DirectMessages().FirstOrDefault()` is calling database in every-iteration, it will take time. Why not use this instead:

```
using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
     var directMessage = db.DirectMessages().FirstOrDefault();
     foreach (long r in Recipients) //Recipients has 1800 items.
     {
         var temp = new DirectMessage();
         temp = directMessage;
         temp.SenderProfileImageUrl = "https://www.google.com.sa/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png";    
     }
}
```

Updated Answer:

```
var directMessages = db.DirectMessages.ToList();

foreach (long r in Recipients)
                {
                    MsgObj = new AllMsgsClass();

                    MsgObj.LastMsg = directMessages.Where(a => (a.SenderID == r || a.RecipientID == r)).OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedDate).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

                    try
                    {
                        if (MsgObj.LastMsg.MsgSort == "Sent")
                            MsgObj.LastMsg.RecipientProfileImageUrl = "https://avatars.io/twitter/" + MsgObj.LastMsg.RecipientScreenName + "/small";

                        else
                            MsgObj.LastMsg.SenderProfileImageUrl = "https://avatars.io/twitter/" + MsgObj.LastMsg.SenderScreenName + "/small";
                    }
                    catch (Exception dd)
                    {
                        string x = dd.Message;
                    }

                    MsgObj.SortOrder = Convert.ToDateTime(MsgObj.LastMsg.CreatedDate);
                    AllMSGsList.Add(MsgObj);
                }
```

Comment: Because I'm not actually calling FirstOrDefault, I just put it like this to test that the where clause is not the issue.
The original command is:
temp = db.DirectMessages.Where(a => (a.SenderID == r || a.RecipientID == r)).OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedDate).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Do you need to call the database with every iteration?

Comment: I updated the question adding the real code, so maybe you can get an idea of why I need to call the db every iteration.

Comment: If you can take db.DirectMessages.ToList(); to a variable and iterate from it, you can save database calls from 1800 to 1. Maybe you wouldn't need to call database again until a new change. I have updated the answer.

Comment: BINGO! it worked in less than a second!!!!
It actually make sense! instead of reaching the DB each iteration it's just accessing the local List..
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Once I faced the similar issue and I followed the below steps, I hope it will help you.
This will also help to generate edmx faster.
Setting the compatibility level of the database to 110 has worked for me.
To check the compatibility level, run this script:

```
select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name = 'YOUR_DB_NAME'
```

To set the compatibility level, use this script:

```
alter database YOUR_DB_NAME set compatibility_level = 110
```